# How to display multiple images in sweet alert 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I'm building an Angular 2 application and is utilizing sweet alert 2 in parts of it. I need multiple images (at least two) to be displayed simultaneously in the pop-up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `<img>` tags into the html parameter like so

```
swal({
    title: '<u>example</u>',
    type: 'info',
    html:
    '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'+ 
    '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">',
    showCloseButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    focusConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
    confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
    cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
    cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down',
});
```

This will allow you to add as many images as you like (Just keep adding your image tags). Hope this helps good luck!

Comment: No problem :) I am glad to help.